# Creating groups based on connectedness

Tags: r, network-analysis, r-neo4j

A network is given.

```
nodes <- data.frame( id = 1:8, label = paste0("Node", 1:8))
edges <- data.frame(from = from, to = to)
library(visNetwork ) # you can use anyone of igraph, rneo4j as well
visNetwork(nodes, edges)
```

[image]

As we are looking for connected networks, we got 2 connected networks(CN) here.
 First CN : (1,2,5,6,7) and 
 Second CN : (3,4,8)

we attach a group_id to each CN. So
 each node of the first CN has group_id 1 and that of second CN, group_id 2.

Final aim is to create a column of group_id by **using some algorithms**.

In the above case, by observing the image

```
 group_id <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2)
 modified_nodes <- cbind(nodes,group_id)
```

Comment: Please add `from` and `to` to your post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `visNetwork`, but it seems to be focused on visualisation rather than analysis of graphs. Thus, I propose an `igraph` solution.

The `igraph` object can be directly created from your data frame `edges` and plotted with `plot()`:

```
library(igraph)
from <- c(8, 4, 1, 2, 5, 5)
to <- c(4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7)
edges <- data.frame(from = from, to = to)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed = FALSE)
plot(g)
```

[image]

`igraph` offers many functions  to analyze a graph. You can get the various disconnected components of the graph with `components()`:

```
components(g)
## $membership
## 8 4 1 2 5 3 6 7 
## 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 
## 
## $csize
## [1] 3 5
## 
## $no
## [1] 2
```

`$membership` is exactly what you asked for. So this would give you a data frame of all the vertices with the number of the component they belong to:

```
memb <- components(g)$membership
nodes <- data.frame(id = names(memb),
                    group_id = memb)
nodes <- nodes[order(nodes$id), ]
nodes
##   id group_id
## 1  1        2
## 2  2        2
## 3  3        1
## 4  4        1
## 5  5        2
## 6  6        2
## 7  7        2
## 8  8        1
```

Alternatively, you could add the column `group_id` to your data frame `nodes`:

```
nodes <- data.frame( id = 1:8, label = paste0("Node", 1:8))
nodes$group_id <- components(g)$membership[as.character(nodes$id)]
```

Note that you need to convert `nodes$id` to character to make sure that you actually index with names.